# Hand over parameters from a MediaWiki template to a included one

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I'm using the MediaWiki extension *DynamicPageList (third-party)* which can be used as a template:

```
{{#dpl:
|category=foo
|notcategory=bar
}}
```

I try to use this template in one of my templates which uses more parameter e.g.:

```
{{myTemplate
|category=foo
|notcategory=bar
|mypara1=bla
|mypara2=lala
}}
```

*myTemplate* looks like this:

```
do something with mypara1
...
do something with mypara2
...
{{#dpl:
|category=foo
|notcategory=bar
}}
```

I know my parameters but *#dpl:* can use one or many parameters.

How can I separate my parameters from the *#dpl:* ones? And how can I just hand over the parameters which belongs to *#dpl:*?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Why don't you just pass them on?

Comment: Well, the question is how? Sometimes I have only a `category`, sometimes two, or I can use a `namespace` parameter or I can use a conbination of all of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I came up with the following solution:

DPL has an additional template [`#dplreplace`](http://www.google.com/). I'm using this to parse my parameters.

Call the template:

```
{{myTemplate
  | filter=category:foo;notcategory:bar
  | mypara1=bla
  | mypara2=lala
}}
```

In the template I replace the `:` by `=` and `;` by `{{!}}`.

```
{{#dpl:
  | {{#dplreplace: {{#dplreplace: {{{filter}}} | /:/ | = }} | /;/ | {{!}} }}
  | ordermethod = sortkey
  | suppresserrors = true
}}
```

NOTE: [`{{!}}`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:!) is a template which is replaced by `|`.

Regards;
Ray

Comment: You don't even necessarily need the inner `#dplreplace`: named parameter values (but not names) can contain equals signs just fine, as in `filter=category=foo;notcategory=bar`. Mind you, readability may be a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your issue, but you can just pass the parameters on to DPL, just like you would to a template, or another [parser function](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions). You might want to add an empty default in most cases:

**myTemplate:**

```
do something with {{{mypara1}}}
do something with {{{mypara2}}}

{{#dpl:
  |category    = {{{category|}}}    <!-- default to empty string -->
  |notcategory = {{{notcategory|}}} <!-- default to empty string -->
}}
```

**Call it like this:**

```
{{myTemplate
  |category=foo
  |notcategory=bar
  |mypara1=bla
  |mypara2=lala
}}
```

**Will work with missing parameters too:**

```
{{myTemplate
  |category=foo
  |mypara1=bla
  |mypara2=lala
}}
```

Comment: Hi Leo, many thanks for your answer. Your solution will cover most of the cobinations but it won't work if I use one parameter twice which is allowed in DPL. Regards, Ray

Comment: No, template variables in MediaWiki must be unique. You have to either separate them (`category_1`, `category_2`), or use a parser function to split a string with several ones (`categories=aaa,bbb,ccc`)

Comment: Hi Leo, with your keyword _parser function_ in mind I came up with a solution which fulfill my requirements. See my one answer. Thanks Ray